# Adding a node to the end of a linked list but not able to access the last node

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been having troubles adding a new node at the end of a singly linked-list.

When I print the list out, I don't seem to be able to access the last node.

```
if (head == nullptr)
{
    head = newNode;
}
else
{
    record* current = head;

    while (current->next != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
}

//Writing data to record.

newNode->name = name;
newNode->highscore = highscore;
newNode->initials = initials;
newNode->plays = plays;
newNode->revenue = revenue;

record* test = head;
while (test->next != nullptr)
{
    cout << test->name << endl;
    test = test->next;
}
```

Comment: Keeping a tail pointer would make this a lot easier. The code that is specific to the data being held shouldn't be in your List class at all. The list is a container, it shouldn't be tailored to any specific data. The specific issue you're having is a simple off-by-one. Your print loop exits when `test->next` is `nullptr`, so the final `test` is not printed.

Comment: After the line `current->next = newNode;`, you need to write `newNode->next = nullptr` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answer is good and necessary, I think it can be handled in a simpler manner. Here's an example `Node`.

```cpp
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node* next = nullptr;

  Node(int val) : data(val) {}
}
```

By default-initializing the pointer to `nullptr`, you don't have to constantly worry about it throughout your list class implementation. Every declared `Node` will automatically set the pointer to `nullptr` for you.

Comment: Nice one. I also realized it that it would prevent such errors inherently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `nullptr` after adding a new node to the list. Also, you should print the list till you reach `nullptr`

```
if (head == nullptr)
{
    head = newNode;
}
else
{
    record* current = head;

    while (current->next != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
}

//Writing data to record.

newNode->name = name;
newNode->highscore = highscore;
newNode->initials = initials;
newNode->plays = plays;
newNode->revenue = revenue;

record* test = head;
while (test != nullptr)
{
    cout << test->name << endl;
    test = test->next;
}
```

Comment: Presumably one would initialize the fields of `newNode`, including `next`, *before* trying to insert `newNode` into the list, rather then *after*.